# Get the header lines of protein sequences that start with specific amino acid in FASTA

Tags: perl, fasta

Hi guys so I have been trying to use PERL to print only the headers (the entire >gi line) of protein sequences that start with "MAD" or "MAN" (the first 3 aa) from a FASTA file. But I couldn't figure out which part went wrong. 
Thanks in advance!

```
#!usr/bin/perl
use strict;

my $in_file = $ARGV[0];
open( my $FH_IN, "<", $in_file );    ###open to fileholder
my @lines = <$FH_IN>;
chomp @lines;
my $index = 0;

foreach my $line (@lines) {
    $index++;
    if ( substr( $line, 0, 3 ) eq "MAD" or substr( $line, 0, 3 ) eq "MAN" ) {
        print "@lines [$index-1]\n\n";
    } else {
        next;
    }
}
```

This is a short part of the FASTA file, the header of the first seq is what I am looking for

```
>gi|16128078|ref|NP_414627.1| UDP-N-acetylmuramoyl-L-alanyl-D-glutamate:meso-diaminopimelate ligase [Escherichia coli str. K-12 substr. MG1655] MADRNLRDLLAPWVPDAPSRALREMTLDSRVAAAGDLFVAVVGHQADGRRYIPQAIAQGVAAIIAEAKDE ATDGEIREMHGVPVIYLSQLNERLSALAGRFYHEPSDNLRLVGVTGTNGKTTTTQLLAQWSQLLGEISAV MGTVGNGLLGKVIPTENTTGSAVDVQHELAGLVDQGATFCAMEVSSHGLVQHRVAALKFAASVFTNLSRD HLDYHGDMEHYEAAKWLLYSEHHCGQAIINADDEVGRRWLAKLPDAVAVSMEDHINPNCHGRWLKATEVN
```

Comment: `print "@lines [$index-1] ...` doesn't make much sense. print the ENTIRE array? is `[$index-1]` supposed to be an attempt at printing the previous line, or actually printing $index-1 in brackets, e.g. if you're on line 10, then actually print `[9]`?

Comment: ya on line 10 and want to print line 9, if line 10 fills the requirement

Comment: then you'd want `$prev = $index - 1; print "$lines[$prev]"` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you want to know how to improve your code, here is a commented version of your program with some suggestions on how you could change it.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
```

You should also add the `use warnings` pragma, which enables warnings (as you might expect).

```
my $in_file = $ARGV[0];
```

It's a good idea to check that `$ARGV[0]` is defined, and to give an appropriate error message if it isn't, e.g.

```
my $in_file = $ARGV[0] or die "Please supply the name of the FASTA file to process";
```

If `$ARGV[0]` is not defined, Perl executes the `die` statement.

```
open( my $FH_IN, "<", $in_file );  # open to fileholder
```

You should check that the script is able to open the input file; you can use a similar structure to the previous statement, by adding a `die` statement:

```
open( my $FH_IN, "<", $in_file ) or die "Could not open $in_file: $!";
```

The special variable `$!` holds the error message as to why the file could not be opened (e.g. it doesn't exist, no permission to read it, etc.).

```
my @lines = <$FH_IN>;
chomp @lines;
my $index = 0;

foreach my $line (@lines) {
    $index++;
    if ( substr( $line, 0, 3 ) eq "MAD" or substr( $line, 0, 3 ) eq "MAN" ) {
         print "@lines [$index-1]\n\n";
```

This is the problem point in the script. Firstly, the correct way to access an item in the array is using `$lines[$index-1]`. Secondly, the first item in an array is at index 0, so line 1 of the file will be at position 0 in `@lines`, line 4 at position 3, etc. Because you've already incremented the index, you're printing the line *after* the header line. The problem can easily be fixed by incrementing `$index` at the end of the loop.

```
    }
    else {
       next;
    }
```

Using `next` isn't really necessary here because there is no code following the `else` statement, so there's nothing to gain from telling Perl to skip the rest of the loop.

The fixed code would look like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

my $in_file = $ARGV[0] or die "Please supply the name of the FASTA file to be processed";
open( my $FH_IN, "<", $in_file ) or die "Could not open $in_file: $!";
my @lines = <$FH_IN>;
chomp @lines;

my $index = 0;
foreach my $line (@lines) {
    if ( substr( $line, 0, 3 ) eq "MAD" or substr( $line, 0, 3 ) eq "MAN" ) {
        print "$lines[$index-1]\n\n";
    }
    $index++;
}
```

I hope that is helpful and clear!

Comment: Don't forget to check `open` for failure.

Answer (score 2):

Your print statement is buggy.  Should probably be:

```
print "$lines[$index-1]\n\n";
```

However, it's typically better to just process a file line by line unless there is a specific reason you need to slurp the entire thing:

```
#!usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use autodie;

my $file = shift;

#open my $fh, "<", $in_file;
my $fh = \*DATA;

while (<$fh>) {
    print if /^>/ && <$fh> =~ /^MA[DN]/;
}

__DATA__
>gi|16128078|ref|NP_414627.1| UDP-N-acetylmuramoyl-L-alanyl-D-glutamate:meso-diaminopimelate ligase [Escherichia coli str. K-12 substr. MG1655] 
MADRNLRDLLAPWVPDAPSRALREMTLDSRVAAAGDLFVAVVGHQADGRRYIPQAIAQGVAAIIAEAKDE
ATDGEIREMHGVPVIYLSQLNERLSALAGRFYHEPSDNLRLVGVTGTNGKTTTTQLLAQWSQLLGEISAV
MGTVGNGLLGKVIPTENTTGSAVDVQHELAGLVDQGATFCAMEVSSHGLVQHRVAALKFAASVFTNLSRD
HLDYHGDMEHYEAAKWLLYSEHHCGQAIINADDEVGRRWLAKLPDAVAVSMEDHINPNCHGRWLKATEVN
–
```

Outputs:

```
>gi|16128078|ref|NP_414627.1| UDP-N-acetylmuramoyl-L-alanyl-D-glutamate:meso-diaminopimelate ligase [Escherichia coli str. K-12 substr. MG1655]
```

Comment: strange I change the @ in @lines[$index-1] to $, still it doesn't give the header lines

Comment: Perhaps actually share some sample data?  Are the header lines that you're talking about actually before the data that is matching?

Comment: ###This is a short part of it, the header of the first seq is what I am looking for                            >gi|16128078|ref|NP_414627.1| UDP-N-acetylmuramoyl-L-alanyl-D-glutamate:meso-diaminopimelate ligase [Escherichia coli str. K-12 substr. MG1655]
MADRNLRDLLAPWVPDAPSRALREMTLDSRVAAAGDLFVAVVGHQADGRRYIPQAIAQGVAAIIAEAKDE
ATDGEIREMHGVPVIYLSQLNERLSALAGRFYHEPSDNLRLVGVTGTNGKTTTTQLLAQWSQLLGEISAV
MGTVGNGLLGKVIPTENTTGSAVDVQHELAGLVDQGATFCAMEVSSHGLVQHRVAALKFAASVFTNLSRD
HLDYHGDMEHYEAAKWLLYSEHHCGQAIINADDEVGRRWLAKLPDAVAVSMEDHINPNCHGRWLKATEVN

Comment: Edit your question to add that information.  I take it you want the `>gi` line printed if the next line begins with MAD or MAN?

Comment: Thanks for your help, but I am just wondering what went wrong in my code, hope to learn from mistakes.

Comment: Update/correct the data in your question, and perhaps I/we could advise you better.  I suspect your data is missing newlines.